# Verbs associated with “Kommentar”

Tags: standard-german, verb-usage, spoken-language

What are the german verbs that are used with *Kommentar*? I mean how do you say: drop a comment, leave a comment? Which verbs are *Kommentar* restricted to?

Comment: http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/ is a good source for researching collocations.

Answer (score 9):

First of all, there is of course the verb *kommentieren* (to comment) itself. But if I understand you correctly you are out for verbs that you can use together with the noun *Kommentar*. It is difficult, if not impossible, to give a complete list, but here are some of the most common (IMHO):

- einen Kommentar lesen, schreiben, abgeben, verfassen, hinterlassen
- etwas mit einem Kommentar versehen
- zu etwas einen Kommentar geben
- in einem Kommentar nachschlagen (note that *Kommentar* can also denote a book with explanations about some other book, like *ein Kommentar zur Bibel oder zum Grundgesetz*)

We are not a dictionary service here, so I leave it to you to learn about the different meanings of these verbs in conjunction with *Kommentar*. Feel free to come back if you have specific questions about any of them (post new questions then).

Comment: what about "einen Kommentar machen" ?

Comment: @Bergmann: I don't think anyone would say that.

Comment: [Wortschatz Leipzig](http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/cgi-portal/de/wort_www?site=208&Wort_id=148719) adds only the somewhat debatable *posten*, *abdrucken* und *anfügen*.

Comment: so does it require for using "für","an" or "zu", i hope my following sentence is correct!
"Leider kann ich für dieses Thema keinen Kommentar abgeben,weil es nicht an mich geht."

Comment: @Bergmann "machen" would probably be understood, but it sounds as you didn't know the right verb. - It is "**zu** etwas einen Kommentar abgeben", so your sentence should read "Leider kann ich zu diesem Thema keinen Kommentar abgeben, weil es mich nichts angeht."

Answer (score -3):

Das Verb ist:

> kommentieren

Viele Verben werden auf diese Weise (durch Anhängen der Endsilbe *-ieren*) gebildet. Diese Silbe drück aus, dass man das, was im Wortstamm steht, erzeugt, oder sonstwie verwendet:

- Tapete
  tapezieren = Tapeten an eine Wand kleben
- Musik
  musizieren = Musik machen
- Lack
  lackieren = Lack auftragen
- **Kommentar

  kommentieren** = einen Kommentar abgeben

Es muss aber ergänzt werden, dass dieses Schema sich nicht auf auf alle Nomen anwenden lässt.